# When we use tasks (i.e. `Runnable` or `Callable<T>`) and `ExecutorService`, can we still use the synchronization constructs used for threads?

Tags: java, synchronization, task, future, executorservice

When concurrency programming by explicitly creating threads, we can use  synchronization constructs (e.g. `synchronized`, `Object.wait()`, `Object.notify()`, and `Object.notifyAll()`, or`Lock` and its `lock()` and `unlock()` methods, `Condition` and its `await()` and `signal()` methods).

When we use tasks (i.e. `Runnable` or `Callable<T>`), `ExecutorService` and maybe `Future`, instead of explicitly creating threads, can we still use the synchronization constructs used for threads?

If yes, could you point me to some references or examples?

Do tasks (i.e. `Runnable` or `Callable<T>`), `ExecutorService` and maybe `Future` use some synchronization constructs which are not used by threads?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Sure, why would tasks/executors mean that we can't use synchronization constructs? Are you having trouble with something specific? Have you read any of JCIP?

Comment: You can use any of the ones you have mentioned. You don't *tend* to use anything like wait or notify, though.

Comment: @Matt Thanks. I am reading some books on concurrency programming in java, but I didn't find tasks (i.e. `Runnable` or `Callable<T>`), `ExecutorService` and maybe `Future` use synchronization constructs.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks. Could you point me to some references or examples?

Do tasks (i.e. Runnable or Callable<T>), ExecutorService and maybe `Future` use some synchronization constructs which are not used by threads?

Comment: @Ben not really... It's just any code which happens to use these things.